# Hamburger button log in goes to the bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create the login from the right side go to the top of the hamburger button menu when it becomes responsive (obviously inside of it with the other tabs). I am assuming that I would have to write a media query or if there is a way to apply a different class in that media query...but I have no idea how to do it. Also, I am using bootstrap for it.
This is what I have so far:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HEALTHY LIFE FITNESS</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Clubs</a>
                <li><a href="#">Classes</a>
                    <li><a href="#">Training</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Pilates</a>
                             <li><a href="#">Join</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    <button type="button" id="login" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right" style="margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;">Log In</button>


        </div>
</div><!--end navbar-->
```

**CSS:**

```
 #navbar{background-color: rgb(18,18,28);}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
      top: 1px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 2px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      position: relative;
      transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
      top: 6px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
      background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
      top: -6px;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
              $(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass("active")
              });
        });
```

Comment: try with flexbox order. I guess it will help you https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#order

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3. Do you think might be better to switch?